# How to avoid using sudo after creating a new partition in a linux server

Tags: linux, sudo

After creating a new partition (and mounting), for every operation I wish to make I have to use sudo command beforehand. For example, in order to make a new directory: `mkdir new_dir` would be denied, but `sudo mkdir new_dir` would work. Is there a way to avoid using the sudo command?

(I'm sorry if my question is not appropriate for this site, I normally would ask my lab engineer, however he is not available for few days, and I am completely unfamiliar with servers administration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bascially two options:

1. `sudo chown -R $USER /your_mount_point` to make the partition owned by your own user.
2. `sudo -i` to start a shell with superuser permissions.